# Validating XML with XSD and xmlns=""

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I have the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<song id="id1" 
          xmlns="urn:Test:Song:1.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="urn:Test:Song:1.0 song.xsd">
  <name>name1</name>
</song>
```

It fails to validate against the XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:Test:Song:1.0" 
               targetNamespace="urn:Test:Song:1.0" 
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

  <xs:element name="song">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

in Eclipse and Visual Studio. In Eclipse the error is:
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'name'. One of '{name}' is expected.

Validation succeeds for the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<song id="id1" 
          xmlns="urn:Test:Song:1.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="urn:Test:Song:1.0 song.xsd">
  <name xmlns="">name1</name>
</song>
```

The only difference is xmlns="" on the name element. Is there a way to make validation succeed on the first without the use of "no namespace"? What exactly is causing the first XML to fail?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` attribute to your schemas `<xs:schema>` element.

Only globally defined elements and attributes are automatically in the schemas target namespace. Elements that are defined within a `<complexType>` definition are said to be local. Attribute `elementFormDefault` defines whether local elements should be qualified or not. For attributes there is `attributeFormDefault` attribute.

The default value of these attributes is `unqualified`. Therefore in your schema the element `<name>` is thought not to have a namespace URI. Usually all elements are desired to be in the target namespace so using `elementFormDefault="qualified"` attribute is a common practice. Attributes on the other hand usually should not have a namespace so `attributeFormDefault` is often omitted.

More info in the W3C Recommendation http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#ref50